# PHP session.cookie_secure true spams session files

Tags: php, session

I know that `session.cookie_secure(true)` sends session cookies only on https.

But on a `http` call it spams the (default) `/temp/` folder with useless session files.

Why is that and how could i prevent that?
(assuming that we dont know we are on a http call)

Test:

```
    // before execution
    # ls -la /tmp/
    # <empty>

    // controller call ...
    ini_set('session.cookie_secure', true);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
    return $this->getResponse()->ok("ok",[
        var_export($_SESSION, true),
    ]);

    // after execution 1
    # ls -la /tmp/
    # sess_819ca3baf7333e61e0e7d7669d42e969

    // after execution 2
    # ls -la /tmp/
    # sess_819ca3baf7333e61e0e7d7669d42e969
    # sess_ba2b00480fc7ac7be6bd74ea95e7b741

    // after execution 3
    # ls -la /tmp/
    # sess_424e3b79c6fbe8f18e141b2997699a9d
    # sess_819ca3baf7333e61e0e7d7669d42e969
    # sess_ba2b00480fc7ac7be6bd74ea95e7b741

    // ... and so on.
```

*No cookies send as expected. But how do we prevent spamming the session folder?*

Comment: It's not spam. You shouldn't worry about it. PHP will clean up old session files (in most distributions). Your PHP code instructs the server to create a session. What else do you expect from it other than to do create that file? You could, however, check if client connects on HTTPS and if not, skip session handling related code.

Comment: If you want the site to behave differently on HTTP than it does on HTTPS you can add a conditional based on `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`. I'm not sure this is a good idea though, I'd generally just redirect the HTTP traffic to the HTTPS address.

Comment: Redirect sounds good. I just wondered about if somebody did not care or forgot to check for http calls. With limited space an attacker could spam the server via http and bring the server down (disk full).